# How to keep Azure Application Logging enabled?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a website hosted on Azure. I am using Trace.Error to output all my error logs to file system. However when I enable Application Logging on Azure website, it only remains enabled for 12 hours.
This is also confirmed in this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/StreamingDiagnosticsTraceLoggingFromTheAzureCommandLinePlusGlimpse.aspx

Now I will like to keep storing error logs indefinitely (i.e. till my website is live). I am not sure if I am missing the point here. How can I keep logging enabled forever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store your logs in Azure Storage (tables or blobs). This doesn't have the 12 hour constraint that the file system does.

[image]